# Include API documentation in SWT

Tags: java, swt

I have java API documentation for my project. I need to include it in the SWT application. I searched the internet and found there is a browser widget available. Is there any simple method available so that I can simply set the location of the URL and  can  navigate the HTML pages.

Comment: Well, what about that browser widget? Did you try it out? It worked for me just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will find plenty of examples in the [SWT snippets](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/)